# Evaluate the definite integral and substitute

Tags: calculus

solving for definite integral. 
I substitute $4x+6$ with $U$ and solved for $du=4dx$
$$\int_0^1 x^2 \sqrt{4x+6}\ dx$$

Comment: Please check my edit to make sure it matches the question you are asking.  Wait, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

After making your $u$-substitution, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4}\int_6^{10} \left(\frac{u - 6}{4}\right)^2\sqrt{u} \, du
&= \frac{1}{64}\int_6^{10} (u^2 - 12u + 36)u^{1/2} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{64}\int_6^{10} (u^{5/2} - 12u^{3/2} + 36u^{1/2}) \, du \\
\end{align*}
From there, it remains to apply power rule in reverse and do some tedious but simple arithmetic.